# Proper way of conditionting with mysql to update different column with different conditions

Tags: mysql

```
column1 = value     WHERE cond='1'
column2 = value     WHERE cond='2'
```

In the example above.
Is this the right way to code it in mysql

```
UPDATE table SET (column1='value' WHERE cond='1') OR (column2='value' WHERE cond='2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
   table
SET
   column1 = (CASE cond WHEN '1' THEN 'value' ELSE column1 END)
 , column2 = (CASE cond WHEN '2' THEN 'value' ELSE column2 END)
WHERE
  cond IN ('1', '2')
;
```

Comment: Edited to add your comment